# How to know if the textbox has lost focus due to a button click?

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox for which i have written the `blur` event handler and i have another button for which i have the `click` event written. i dont want to dispatch the `blur` event if it's due a click on the button.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('yourblurbutton').bind('blur', function() {
    yourblurfunction();
});
$('yourclickbutton').bind('click', function() {
    //your click code
});
$('yourclickbutton').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('yourblurbutton').unbind('blur');
});
$('yourclickbutton').bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('yourblurbutton').bind('blur', function() {
        yourblurfunction();
    });
});
yourblurfunction() {
   // your blur function
}
```

The mouseover event will be triggered before the blur, so it makes us able to unbind the blur. On mouseout, we simple add the blur again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function blurr() {
     alert('blur')   
}
$(function(){
    $('textarea').blur(function(){blurr()})
    $(':button').click(function(){alert('click')})
    $(':button').hover(function(){
        $('textarea').unbind('blur');
    },function(){
        $('textarea').bind('blur',function() {blurr()});
    })
})
```

Eg: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/zm2kk/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)